# Hadoop: LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable

Tags: java, hadoop

I want to take a mean value of a temperature given in an input file and my Mapper and Reducer synatax seems fine to me but I am still getting the following error:

```
 Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore
    13/02/17 08:03:28 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201302170552_0009_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
    java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable
        at org.apache.hadoop.examples.TempMeasurement$TempMapper.map(TempMeasurement.java:26)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

My Mapper function is this:

```
public static class TempMapper extends Mapper<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, FloatWritable>{

@Override
protected void map(IntWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    //code for getting date and temperature

    String temp = columns.get(3);
    context.write(new IntWritable(year), new FloatWritable(Float.valueOf(temp)));
}
}
```

And Reduce is:

```
  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<IntWritable, FloatWritable, IntWritable ,FloatWritable> {
    private FloatWritable result = new FloatWritable();

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<FloatWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

      //code for making calculations    

      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }
```

Input file is as:

```
11111 , 0,19900101, 44.04 ,
11112, 0, 19900102, 50.00,
11113, 3, 19910203, 30.00,
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key class of a mapper that maps text files is always `LongWritable`. That is because it contains the byte offset of the current line and this could easily overflow an integer.

Basically you need to change your code to this:

```
public static class TempMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, FloatWritable>{

  @Override
  protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
       //code for getting date and temperature
       String temp = columns.get(3);
       context.write(new IntWritable(year), new FloatWritable(Float.valueOf(temp)));
  }
}
```

Comment: I had put Object when I realized before your answer and it was compiled successfully. But I guess, LongWritable would be more appropriate to use here. Thanks for the answer.